# how do you convert a series to a dataframe to concat to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

i have a dataframe with multiple rows. i need to sum any number of the rows and add the resultant total as a new row to the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
               'B': [4, 5, 6]},
              index=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])

df_1 = df.loc['X': 'Z'].sum()
df_1.name = 'Key Totals'
```

df_1 is a series with name 'Key Totals'. I want to add a row to df with the name 'Key Totals' (index value).

so i transpose df_1

```
df_2 = df_1.T
```

to add this to df i use this code:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df_2])
```

but this gives me this:

```
     A    B     0
X  1.0  4.0   NaN
Y  2.0  5.0   NaN
Z  3.0  6.0   NaN
A  NaN  NaN   6.0
B  NaN  NaN  15.0
```

i want:

```
              A    B     
X            1.0  4.0
Y            2.0  5.0
Z            3.0  6.0
Key Totals   6.0 15.0
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: thanks much Chrysophylax. i really like your solution. question: suppose i only wanted to add rows Y and Z? would df.loc["Key Totals"] = df["y": "Z'].sum() work?

Comment: thanks again Chrysophylax. answered my question to you. it works as you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The transpose of series is itself: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.T.html

If you want to use your method, you should convert to a dataframe first:

```
pd.concat([df, df_1.to_frame().T])
```

but easier would be to do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
               'B': [4, 5, 6]},
              index=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])

df.loc["Key Totals"] = df.sum()
```

which has output:

```
            A   B
X           1   4
Y           2   5
Z           3   6
Key Totals  6  15
```